# Running a jQuery function on all divs with different values but same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xslt

What I'm trying to do is run a jQuery function that converts a number score into a bar rating system using the score as a percentage to set the width of the bar. The `div`s and the scores inside of the `div`s are being generated dynamically from XML with XSL.

The problem is that the function is taking the score from the first DIV and applying it to all subsequent DIVs instead of taking the score from each DIV separately. For reference, `.Product_Rating_Score_Overall` is the score, `.ratingBar` is the grey background behind my score bar, `.ratingOverall` is the green bar that has its width adjusted to reflect the score percentage. Here is an image of my rating system(as you can see the rating of 2.0 from the first DIV is being transferred to the other DIVs. The ratings for the other DIVs should be as follows 7.0 6.0, 6.0, 6.0 - these are just dummy scores for now):

[image: ratingsytem]

Here is my html code:

```
<div id="F26_ResultsDiv" style="display:none">
  <div class="items"><div class="ColOne">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="otherStuff">
        <span>Kindermat Basic Red/Blue</span>
          <div class="overall"><span><span class="content">
           <ul>
            <li class="Product_Rating_Score_Overall">2.00</li>
           </ul>
        </span></span>
      <div class="ratingBar">
    <div class="ratingOverall"> 
</div></div></div></div></div>
```

Here is my jQuery code:

```
  $('.overall').each( function() {
       var score = parseFloat($('.Product_Rating_Score_Overall').text()).toFixed(1);
       console.log(score);
        var scorePerc = score * 10;
        $('.ratingOverall').width(scorePerc + '%');
        $('.Product_Rating_Score_Overall').text(score);
    });
```

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks so much.

Comment: When is the jQuery running?  If it is running before the page is fully loaded/built then it may not be seeing all of elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **$(this)** and **[find](https://api.jquery.com/find/)()** function.

for each element with class *overall* you find under it the element with class *Product_Rating_Score_Overall*

```
$('.overall').each( function() {
   var score = parseFloat($(this).find('.Product_Rating_Score_Overall').text()).toFixed(1);
   console.log(score);
    var scorePerc = score * 10;
    $(this).find('.ratingOverall').width(scorePerc + '%');
    $(this).find('.Product_Rating_Score_Overall').text(score);
});
```

Comment: Both you and Kenneth were correct but you beat him by a minute. I really appreciate it. I was banging my head against a wall for like two hours on this one. You're both awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You need to localize your selector:

```
$('.overall').each( function() {
   var score = parseFloat($(this).find('.Product_Rating_Score_Overall').text()).toFixed(1);
   console.log(score);
    var scorePerc = score * 10;
    $(this).find('.ratingOverall').width(scorePerc + '%');
    $(this).find('.Product_Rating_Score_Overall').text(score);
});
```

Update: added fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mbho2bjj/5/

Comment: @Tizo Mine's not exactly incorrect, nor was it not the fastest post or lacking a comprehensive example...

Comment: You're absolutely right. Yours was correct as well. Thanks so much. Sorry for not mentioning you. As far as who posted first, I'm just going by the answered by time on the posts and Elheni beat you by a minute.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your second line and the other references being global and not localized properly. You should be changing it to grab the local value, not the first one each time that appears on the global scope, which is why you are getting the functionality you see now. Right now you think its not working but it is working exactly as it was written. By adjusting the code to act on the local variables inside each `'.overall'` we will get the proper results that you are looking for.

Try changing that code like this:

```
$('.overall').each( function() {
   var score = parseFloat($(this).find('.Product_Rating_Score_Overall').text()).toFixed(1);
   console.log(score);
    var scorePerc = score * 10;
    $(this).find('.ratingOverall').width(scorePerc + '%');
    $(this).find('.Product_Rating_Score_Overall').text(score);
});
```